# OPX2 syntax for native function : Planisware

Tags: javascript

I just start coding in my intership. I'm new in the field so I hope that you could help me. How could I correct this syntax please? I'm working on OPX2 envt.

`LISTE_DANS` is a function to search in nom the "V2" var

```js
for (var remplace in "OPXCat_Act" where remplace.CallBooleanFormula("\LISTE_DANS"\ (\"nom\"="V2\")"))
{
    alert (remplace);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look to Planisware function description for LISTE_DANS as shown below:

[function example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzsMi.png)

In English it might be the LIST_FIND function.

Then, if you just need to get the objects that have "V2" string as a name that is clearly not a good method to do it.The following example is a better solution.

```
for (var remplace in "OPXCat_Act" where remplace.name == "V2")
{
    alert (remplace);
}
```

Planisware white paper about Opx2 Script would be helpful to get best practices in writing OJS code :)